# The difference between 2 timespans if the second one is on the next day

Tags: c#

Let's say I have 2 timespans (24h format) in C#:

```
TimeSpan start = TimeSpan.Parse("22:11:00");
TimeSpan end = TimeSpan.Parse("01:54:12");
TimeSpan duration = end - start;
```

The problem is that the duration in this case is a negative number, far from the correct result. How to get the correct duration?

Comment: `if(end < start){ end.Add(TimeSpan.Parse("24:00:00")); }`

Comment: Thanks. It works.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if start is 09:00 and end is 10:00 on the following day?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following Unit test

```
[DataRow("16:00", "01:00", "09:00")]
[DataRow("16:00", "21:00", "05:00")]
public void CalculateDuration(string open, string close, string expected) {
    var begin = TimeSpan.Parse(open);
    var end = TimeSpan.Parse(close);

    var actual = end < begin ? (TimeSpan.FromHours(24) - begin) + end : end - begin;

    Assert.AreEqual(TimeSpan.Parse(expected), actual);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Duration()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.duration(v=vs.110).aspx)
 method:

```
TimeSpan duration = (start - end).Duration();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeSpan duration = end - start;
```

**Not**: `start - end` .